# Regex for matching string and not containing substring

Tags: regex, xml

I'm working with some JSF code and need to insert a `stlyeClass` to all `<h:commandButton>`s in the project. The problem is that there are a lot of commandButtons and I don't want to do it manually. Also another problem is that some of the commandButtons already contains styleClass while some doesn't. I would therefore need a regex to find commandButton NOT containing `styleClass` so I first can insert my code there before I edit the rest. Hope my explanation made sense. Please try to answer the problem and not with workarounds.

Many Thanks!

Comment: I gather that you want to do a regex based find&replace in Eclipse on XML-flavored files? If so, better tell/confirm so before getting more downvotes on your question being overly vague. This is at least not a JSF problem. It's sufficient to just treat JSF files as XML files. Regex gurus will understand you better ;)

Comment: Is this a find/replace (as in Ctrl-F) issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the Eclipse Search and Replace Feature, the following regex should work for you. It will add some "unnecessary" whitespaces in some situations, but these can be removed by simple letting eclipse auto-format the whole file again. 
(Select the project root and press `CTRL+Shift+F` for the laziest option - or just ignore the whitespaces.)

To verify it is matching all your command buttons:

- run a file-search on `<h:commandButton` first, write down the number.
- run the replacement on the pattern bellow, compare the matched numbers before attempting the replacement. (It should be the same, not lesser, not greater)

Note: Your styleClass-Attributes must not contain the `"` character!

The regex:

```
<h:commandButton([^>]+(?=styleClass)|)(?:styleClass="([^"]+)")?([^>]*?)(\/?>)
```

The replacement (where `myNewStyleClassForEveryCommandButton` should be the style you want to set):

```
<h:commandButton$1 styleClass="myNewStyleClassForEveryCommandButton $2"$3$4
```

transforms the following example:

```
<h:commandButton />
<h:commandButton>

</h:commandButton>

<h:commandButton styleClass="something" />
<h:commandButton styleClass="something">

</h:commandButton>
<h:commandButton attr="value" styleClass="something more" />
<h:commandButton attr="value" styleClass="something more">

</h:commandButton>
<h:commandButton attr="value" styleClass="something" anotherAttr="somethingElse"/>
<h:commandButton 
  attr="value" 
  styleClass="something" 
  anotherAttr="somethingElse">

</h:commandButton>
```

into this result:

```
<h:commandButton styleClass="myNewStyleClassForEveryCommandButton " />
<h:commandButton styleClass="myNewStyleClassForEveryCommandButton ">

</h:commandButton>

<h:commandButton  styleClass="myNewStyleClassForEveryCommandButton something" />
<h:commandButton  styleClass="myNewStyleClassForEveryCommandButton something">

</h:commandButton>
<h:commandButton attr="value"  styleClass="myNewStyleClassForEveryCommandButton something more" />
<h:commandButton attr="value"  styleClass="myNewStyleClassForEveryCommandButton something more">

</h:commandButton>
<h:commandButton attr="value"  styleClass="myNewStyleClassForEveryCommandButton something" anotherAttr="somethingElse"/>
<h:commandButton 
  attr="value" 
   styleClass="myNewStyleClassForEveryCommandButton something" 
  anotherAttr="somethingElse">

</h:commandButton>
```

https://regex101.com/r/tD0dU9/7

commit and push before attempting this :-)

Comment: Thanks alot!! This really made my day a lot easier :) problem solved! What should I begin looking at to step by step become better at regex?

Comment: @RashidTevez http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html is a good source. It is important that you not only *know the patterns* - you need to understand *how the engine works*. So even if you already know, what `.*?` means - read how the engine processes it to fully grasp what it *actually* means in certain situations. (The website linked has a *Looking Inside The Regex Engine* Section for almost everything). Other than that: Practice makes perfect ;-)

Comment: than you! I appreciate it